# Rank of isogenous elliptic curves

Tags: nt.number-theory, ag.algebraic-geometry

I think that k-isogenous elliptic curves have the same rank as I think rank is an isogeny invariant. However, I am not sure. Does anyone know where could I find a proof? Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An isogeny $A \to B$ is a map $A \to B$ with finite kernel. Choose a splitting of $MW(A)$ into torsion-free and torsion summands. This kernel cannot include any of the torsion-free part of $MW(A)$ and so is injective on the torsion-free part so the rank of $MW(B)$ is at least the rank of $MW(A)$. Since whenever there is an isogeny $ f\colon A \to B$ (say of degree $n$), there is an isogeny $B \to A$ (for example, the one whose composition with $f$ is multiplication by $n$) , this gives you equality.

Comment: What is the " rank part of $A$ " ?

Comment: @Chandan: I think he may be implicitly choosing a splitting of Mordell-Weil into torsion-free and torsion summands.

Comment: I just wanted to point out that it woud be good manners to make the hypotheses explicit.  When you write "k-isogenous", you should tell us what k is; when you talk about the rank, you should be over a k for which the group of k-rational points is finitely generated, etc.

Comment: @Chandan and S.Carnahan - yes, that is correct. Sorry for the lack of clarity.

Comment: Just to be sure I understood correctly, did we use that $A$ is of dimension $1$ here? It seems to me that this argument works in any dimension, right?

Comment: It works in any dimension, so yes, isogenies between abelian varieties also preserve rank.